# CSS Media queries reading wrong width

Tags: html, css, razor, media

I'm trying to set some styles on a page with basic CSS and when I refresh the page to see expected results, all I can see that chrome uses styles from another query which it shouldn't do, when I browse from my phone I see styles from `@media (max-width:1220px) and (min-width:965px)` when it should show styles from `@media (max-width: 767px)`. Anyone had this problem before?

```
@@media (min-width:1221px) {

    //some style
}

/* Tablets and very small desktop screens (if some) */
@@media (max-width:1220px) and (min-width:965px) {

    //some style
}

/* Tablets and very small desktop screens (if some) */
@@media (max-width:964px) and (min-width:768px) {

    //some style
}


@@media (max-width: 767px){

    //some style
}
```

Comment: `@@`: is it a typo?

Comment: I usually also add which types that the query should apply to - like `@media all and (max-width:767px){}` is that not requiered?

Comment: @stender if not defined is `all` by default

Comment: I have tried with ´@media all (max-width: 767px)´ but same result

Comment: @fcalderan A double `@` sign is used when for example using ASP.Net Razor Views, which has the same sign preserved for Razor syntax. A reason to escape Razor syntax is when using a `<style>` element within a Razor view in order to create media queries. Please provide us with a [MCVE] though. We are lacking information in order to help you understand your question.

Comment: thanks @Barrosy ,  good to know

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remove @@media and put one @media

```
@media (min-width:1221px) {

    //some style
}

/* Tablets and very small desktop screens (if some) */
@media (max-width:1220px) and (min-width:965px) {

    //some style
}

/* Tablets and very small desktop screens (if some) */
@media (max-width:964px) and (min-width:768px) {

    //some style
}


@media (max-width: 767px){

    //some style
}
```

Comment: I have dubbed @@ because this styling is in a .cshtml file, so it removes one @ automatically. all other @@ queries work fine.

Comment: Yes the double `@` sign should work fine, that's not causing any problems.